# Angular 6 Material Autocomplete Error on selection

Tags: autocomplete, angular-material, angular6

I am new to frontend development. I am using Angular 6 in my project, and I wanted to implement a typeahead/auto-complete which would fetch the results from the backend using a service. I am able to get the shortlisted results (based on the text provided by the user in the input box), however, as soon as a selection is made `this.docControl.valueChanges` is invoked again, thereby resulting in error. My component is named DocumentSearch, and is as follows:

```
export class DocumentSearchComponent implements OnInit {
  docControl = new FormControl('');
  searchText: string;
  filteredOptions$: Observable<Document[]>;
  isLoading: boolean;

  @Output() documentSelected = new EventEmitter<Document>();

  constructor(private _documentService: DocumentService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions$ = this.docControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        debounceTime(400),
        tap((text: string) => { this.isLoading = true; this.searchText = text; }),
        switchMap((text: string) => this.searchText ? this._documentService
          .getAllMatchingDocument(this.searchText.toLowerCase())
          .pipe(
            finalize(() => this.isLoading = false),
          ) : of([])
        )
      )
    ;
  } 

  public myChangeFunc(event, doc: Document) {
    if (event.source.selected) {
      this.documentSelected.emit(doc);
      this.searchText = doc.documentTitle;
    }
  }

  displayFn(doc?: Document): string | undefined {
     return doc ? doc.documentTitle : undefined;
  }

}
```

The Html template is simple:

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="docControl"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto" >
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let doc of filteredOptions$ | async" (onSelectionChange)="myChangeFunc($event, doc)"
              [value]="doc">
        <span>{{doc.documentTitle}}}</span>
        <small> | ID: {{doc.documentID}}</small>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

When one of the option, is selected from the suggestions, the following error is thrown on the console. `ERROR TypeError: _this.searchText.toLowerCase is not a function`. Also, `myChangeFunc` is invoked with null value in `doc`.

Any help is appreciated. Apparently, on selection, `this.docControl.valueChanges` is fired, that too with object `Document` instead of the text in the input box. I explicitly declared `text` as string, hoping for a class cast exception kind of thing, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using server-side filtering through `getAllMatchingDocument` method.

You can retrieve the list of matching documents from the API when a valid value is typed using the following:

```
// component variable to keep documents
docs: Observable<Document[]>;

// When the value changes, retrieve filtered list from back-end
this.docControl.valueChanges
  .pipe(startWith(null), debounceTime(400))
  .subscribe(val => {
    // only if the value is a valid string and not a selected doc object
    if (typeof val === 'string') {
      this.isLoading = true;
      // Update docs
      this._documentService
        .getAllMatchingDocument(val === null ? '' : val.toLowerCase())
        .subscribe(
          results => {
            this.docs = results;
            this.isLoading = false;
          },
          error => {
            console.log('Error');
          }
        )
    }
  });
```

Modify ngFor:

```
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Pick one" aria-label="Number" matInput [formControl]="docControl"
           [matAutocomplete]="auto" >
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let doc of docs" [value]="doc">
        <span>{{doc.documentTitle}}}</span>
        <small> | ID: {{doc.documentID}}</small>
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the belated response. I was able to solve the problem using brute force (read typeof) in the switchMap command. Also, the problem in getting the `undefined` in (onSelectionEvent) was due incorrect usage - $event.target.value instead of $event during component initialization. Thanks for the troubles.